# AWS Lambda - One function with multiple parameter sets or multiple functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which is pretty general. It queries an Athena Database table, and writes the output to an S3 Bucket. The function is currently set up to accept environment variables for the Database name, table name, output filename and output bucket.

Currently, I call this function with 4 different sets of environment variables, so I have 4 different lambdas, whose code is the same, but whose environment variables are different. Do I need to have 4 different lambdas, or is there a way of having one lambda with 4 environment variable 'sets'?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not keep the env values in SSM Parameter store instead? This way a single function can fetch what it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:  To handle 4 sets of configuration with a single lambda, send a variable (e.g. `type: Foo`) part of the lambda invocation<sup>1</sup>.  As @Marcin suggests, the lambda uses the `type` value to fetch the config variables from the [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) at runtime with the [GetParametersByPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html) API.  Parameters support [hierarchies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-hierarchies.html), so you can store your config using nested variable names like:  `/Foo/db`, `/Foo/table`, `/Bar/table` etc.

---

(1) For example, send `type` in the [event detail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-putevents.html) if event-triggered, or in the SDK `Invoke` command [payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/interfaces/invokecommandinput.html#payload).

Comment: Thanks @fedonev. This works for me. I don't need to use SSM Parameter store though since the parameters aren't confidential. I can simply pass the parameters via ```Input:``` in Cloud Formation JSON. Was this the reason you recommended using it or is there another reason?

Comment: You're welcome, @GideonDeveloper.  SSM Parameters decouple configuration from code.  That's not always super important, though.  Glad you found a solution that works for you!

Comment: I think this relates to what I am wondering about which is if I am able to pass environment variables via events, then I can go from having 4 lambdas to 1. That is, 4 events pointing to 1 lambda. Or I could have one event (since the timing of the functions is all the same) that triggers 4 lambdas where the environment variables are stored in the lambdas. Are you indicating that using SSM Parameters will allow me to have one event and one lambda since I can store the different parameters there? I thought that SSM PS was just for security, like Secrets Manager, but that doesn't seem so.

Comment: Right, @GideonDeveloper, the Param Store is for _any_ config.  Your Lambda needs to know (A) which scenario(s) to run and (B) the actual config values.  Because your answer to A is "always all 4", you are also right that 1 event and 1 lambda works.  What about B? My answer suggests saving config values as Params. Your Lambda calls [GetParametersByPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html) at runtime to lookup the values from the Param Store.  Or you could pass the config values in the event detail.  Also works.

Comment: if I "pass the config values in the event detail", then I will need an event for each config set right? I'm trying to do this in a best-practices kind of way. I think that that would be using SSM PS. If I use that, then would adding a new file to copy just be as simple as going into Parameter Store and just entering the config values? That is, my answer to "(A) which scenario(s) to run " would always be, 'however many scenarios are in SSM PS' and "(B) the actual config values" would be 'whatever values are in SSM PS for the scenarios'. Does that make sense?

Comment: @GideonDeveloper agreed on all but the 1st sentence. Config for all scenarios _could_ fit into in a single event. Your 1 event detail would be a stringified JSON array of scenario configuration objects.  That aside, the rest makes sense.  Why not take this opportunity to learn a new technology? Welcome to Team Parameter Store!

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your help here @fedonev! Happy to be a part of Team Parameter Store :)